# How to make more than 100 callouts per transaction?

Tags: apex, batch, callout

I am new to Salesforce callouts and batch concepts but here is the requirement that I am working on:

Requirement is to get data from a third party API and create lead objects in our salesforce and for this I need to be able to make more than 100 future calls.

For now, I created a simple class and invoke this class from Anonymous Apex window in developer console.

This class makes callouts:

```
public with sharing class CallOutExample {

public void submitHttpRequest(){
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

    req.setMethod('GET');

    req.setEndPoint('http://www.example.com/endpoint');

    Http httpObj = new Http();
    HttpResponse res;
    String jsonString;

    List<Lead> leadObjList = new List<Lead>();

    for(Integer j =0; j <105; j++){

        res = httpObj.send(req);
        jsonString = res.getBody();

        Map<String,Object> jsonMapObj = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);

        List<Object> leadJsonObjList = (List<Object>)jsonMapObj.get('leadJson');

        for(Integer i=0; i<leadJsonObjList.size(); i++){
            // Here I take values for the last name, first name, phone number and everything from each lead Json object
            // and create lead objects and to the list
            Lead leadObj = new Lead(); //Assuming I am setting all the values
            leadObjList.add(leadObj);
        }   

    }

    Database.insert(leadObjList);

}

}
```

And then I am invoking this method with the below code from anonymous apex:

```
CallOutExample obj = new CallOutExample();

obj.submitHttpRequest();
```

Can somebody point me in right direction on how to achieve this:

If I write a batch class, will I be able to make more than 100 callouts? If so how do I implement the start method of the Batchable interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the architecture. You're making ~100 callouts, but you have structured your code as if you're getting multiple lead objects in the body of each response. How many leads are you receiving per callout?

So depending on how many leads you get in each response, that will be your batch (scope) size I think.

Something like this:

```
public with sharing class MyLeadImporterBatchable implements Database.Batchable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    public static final BATCH_SIZE = 10;

    public Iterable<Lead> start (Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        List<Lead> scope = new List<Lead>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < BATCH_SIZE; i++) {

            scope.add(new Lead());
        }

        return scope;
    }

    public void execute (Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Lead> scope) {

        // Make callout

        // Parse response, populate scope with contents

        // Insert scope
    }

    public void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        // Make another callout

        // Parse response
        if (!leadJsonObjList.isEmpty()) {

            Database.executeBatch(new MyLeadImporterBatchable(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically:

- start() - creates X Lead records which will be processed during the execute() method
- execute() - makes the callout & parses the response into the lead
  records, inserts the records
- finish() - makes a second callout to see if there are more records to
  process and if so, queues up another batch class

I'm not too clear on your architecture but that structure should be pretty close to what you need.

Comment: Each callout gives me 50 leads and I dont know how many callouts i need to make..The condition is i should stop making callout when the response is empty from the callout

Comment: In that case my code should be pretty close. Just change BATCH_SIZE to 50, fill out the commented bits and give it a go.

Comment: Davin, What if the first callout response has only 20 leads? Can you help m e on this?

Comment: @javanoob I don't think I'd do it this way -- instead ...the start method would use an iterable and iterator that did repeated callouts until either there were no more to do or the governor limit was reached (and in the latter case, signal the finish to start another batch). The `execute()` would simply insert the leads returned from the iterator as passed via Scope. This all presumes that the 3rd party system can tell the client when there are no more to do and there is a way to index through the 3rd party system's leads without revisiting any

Comment: @crop1645, I followed your approach and this is how I did: in the start method made repeated callouts until the limit is reached or the response from the webservice is empty. If the limit is reached, set the `createAnotherBatch` flag to true so that finish method starts another batch. If the response is empty that means no more leads, I set the flag to false. I like this approach this is neat and clean. Thanks for the Idea!